# how free memory showing as 174G, even i dont have that much RAM

Tags: 12.04, ram

```
    xxx@xxxl:~$ df -h
    Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
    /dev/sda1       228G   42G  174G  20% /
```

what is difference between Normal G and this 173G ?
  Is that all free memory is called Heap ? if i am allocating malloc(10) and in that 10 bytes i am storing thousands of bytes , its storing ?

Comment: That is not your RAM, it is your hard drive, lol

Comment: how to find RAM size ? any command ?

Comment: use `free -m` for ram

Comment: @bodhi.zazen what's the difference to `free -g`?

Comment: gb vs mb, see man free - http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/wily/man1/free.1.html

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're looking at your hard drive...

You have a 250GB hard drive connected, of which you've used 42GB; 174GB is free space.

As far as I know, you're not running a supercomputer, so less then 174GB RAM should work fine **;)**

To see your RAM size use `free -g`.